# How can I select the default header in my PreferenceActivity on tablets?

Tags: android, header, preferenceactivity

I am working with a `PreferenceActivity` that will be fully compatible with **tablets**.

For this, I will work as advised by **Google** in this [page](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/preference/PreferenceWithHeaders.html).

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
}
```

My problem is that I would like to be able to select the default header when the activity is launched.

For instance, I have several headers;

- General Settings
- UI Settings
- Network settings

And depending on which activity I come from, I would like to display the correct settings.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When creating the Intent to invoke the PreferenceActivity, you can add the extra string 'EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT' to specify which fragment should be initially displayed. You pass the name of the fragment you would like to select.

For instance, if you would like to select the General Settings header (and its contents) you can use the following code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExtendedPreferenceActivity.class); // Assume we call it from an other activty
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, GeneralSettingsFragment.class.getName());
startActivity(intent);
```

More information on this can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

In an issue report to Google it is reported that for Android version 3.0 the correct header will not be automatically selected as well. For the issue report and its workaround look here: [issue report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22430).

Comment: I accepted it without test, and will try the code next week, but seems correct. Thank a lot.

Comment: I lost an entire afternoon looking for this.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create PreferenceHeaders dynamically using PreferenceActivity.Header class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.Header.html

Comment: After reading this doc, I don't get it.. Can you be a little bit more specific? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fragment by default:

Here is what I've done:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {

/** Variables **/


/** Constants **/
private static final String CLASSTAG = PreferencesActivity.class.getSimpleName();


/** Class Methods **/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v(CLASSTAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initializeUI();
}

@Override
public Intent getIntent() {
    Log.v(CLASSTAG, "getIntent");
    final Intent modIntent = new Intent(super.getIntent());
    modIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, SettingsFragment.class.getName());
    modIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, true);
    return modIntent;
}


/** Private Functions **/
private void initializeUI() {
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}


/** Classes **/
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_preference);  
        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() { }
}


}
```

and the default xml (as prior HoneyComb versions...):

```
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/preferences_category_1">

        <com.taptime.ui.preferences.ClickPreference
            android:key="@string/preferences_conditions_key"
            android:title="@string/preferences_conditions_title"/>

    </PreferenceCategory> 

    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/preferences_category_2">

        <com.newin.android.ui.widget.ClickPreference
            android:key="@string/preferences_logout_key"
            android:title="@string/preferences_logout_title"
            android:summary="@string/preferences_logout_summary"/>

    </PreferenceCategory> 

</PreferenceScreen>
```